# How to set up DNS server on same machine as web server?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, bind, nslookup

I'm trying to set up a DNS server on the same box as my web server. I have been following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial and others like it but none of them describe what to do if the DNS server is going to be on the same machine and use the same IP address as the web server. I have read in several places that it can be done, but I haven't seen anything about how to do it so I am trying to use the normal way but so far it is not working.

Mostly I'm having trouble understanding what values I should be putting where.

In the tutorial they have a primary DNS server at 10.128.10.11 and they say the FQDN is **ns1.nyc3.example.com**. But in various places they use only **nyc3.example.com**. Is ns1 a special DNS thing or is that just a made up bit for the example?

For example when I do hostname --fqdn on my server I get **123.myserver.local**. Does that mean where it says **ns1.nyc3.example.com** I put **123.myserver.local** and where it says **nyc3.example.com** I put **myserver.local**? Or does it mean that where it says **ns1.nyc3.example.com** I put **ns1.123.myserver.local** and where it says **nyc3.example.com** I put **123.myserver.local**?

In all the different ways that I have tried it, in the end "nslookup 123.myserver.local" never works and I get:

```
Server: 10.128.100.101
Address: 10.128.100.101#53
** server can't find mysite.local: SERVFAIL
```

But "nslookup 10.128.100.101" always returns the right value.

I am wondering if there are other things I am supposed to do to make having them both on the same box work. I would also like to confirm that using .local isn't messing anything up.

Does anyone know what values the tutorial actually wants me to use? Does anyone have a resource they could recommend about having both on the same box? Do any special things need to be done for a .local site?

If you need more information, please let me know. Thanks.